# Mdi Panel Control

Tags: c#-4.0

How to add 2nd childform to mdi parent form "PANEL Control"...??
I am adding child forms to Panel Control of mdi parent form....
i have two child forms, childForm1, childForm2.... 
when i click a button on mdi parent form, childForm1 is added to mdiParent "PANEL Control"...
Know i want to add childForm2 to mdiform "Panel Control", when i click a button on childForm1...
Means i want to add childForm2 from childForm1 button click event, to mdiParent forms "Panel Control"...???

Can anyone Help me....???
Thanks in advance.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use tablelayoutpanel with two columns, in first column show the child1 clicking on second button show next child(2) in next column and hide first column(Column width=0)